# Is anyone here familiar with techniques and/or equipment for performing cerebrospinal fluid transfusions?

Tags: experimental-neuroscience

I am a student at a University and we are discussing putting together a lab assessing the benefits that may be associated with cerebrospinal fluid (CSF) transfusions in Alzheimer's disease mice. So far it looks like from [this paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11552002/) there may have existed a device at one time that could have been modified for our purposes. I contacted Infors AG and the representative believes this device to be out of production. Does anyone here know of anyone who is doing work with CSF transfusions? We are very eager to begin, especially myself and would greatly appreciate any leads as to literature available on this technique or biotech companies that may be able to provide the tools we seek.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the [patent holders of such a device](https://patents.google.com/patent/USH266H/en)?

Comment: I did consider this at one point, though a quick Google search yielded "convicted fraudster." Anyways, I'm not so certain how this experiment would turn out anyhow, and at best it would stand to serve as a proof of concept for CSF dysregulation in AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods section of [Young CSF restores oligodendrogenesis and memory in aged mice via Fgf17](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-04722-0) should cover this (Published May 11, 2022).

Comment: StackExchange wants answers to be self-contained. It's excellent to provide a source, but we don't want *just* a source, we want someone to be able to get at least a general idea from the content posted here. Links should be used to support and for further reading.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Bryan. I’ll try and update my response after I read the publication this summer.